# Root cron job not executing script properly. PATH or HOME directories the problem?

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, cron

So I created the following script in order to update my Ubuntu system and added a cron job, as root, to execute it.

```
#!/bin/bash
if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null; then
   /usr/bin/apt-get update -y;
   /usr/bin/apt-get upgrade -y;
   exit
fi
```

I get the following output in /var/mail/root

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources [250 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources [155 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [526 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [219 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [454 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe          Translation-en [184 kB]
Fetched 2,093 kB in 14s (149 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages will be upgraded:
libnma-common libnma0 network-manager-gnome
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 389 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386     network-manager-gnome i386 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [310 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libnma0 i386 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [73.5 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libnma-common all 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [5,650 B]
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
Fetched 389 kB in 0s (563 kB/s)
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Can someone explain to me what is the problem here? I checked /etc/crontab and can verify PATH contains what it should according to the 'Note' above.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Why won't my script execute correctly?

Comment: Are you actually *using* `/etc/crontab` - or root's personal crontab (e.g. `sudo crontab -e`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron seems not to use the environment which you have, try putting 
`PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'` before your script in the cronjobs list or add it to your script.

e.g.

`* * * * * PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin' myscript.sh`

Comment: That was it. I added the PATH variable to the script and it worked. So when it comes to running a bash script as a cron job for root, environment variables are not set?